# How do I change the text alignment in a radius annotation with AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad

I have two files open in AutoCAD. One uses horizontal text in radius annotation (see the first picture). The second uses a straight line in radius annotation (see the second picture). I cannot find any difference in the settings of the two files. How do I get the second file's annotation like the first?

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Go to `Dimstyle` and change your text alignment setting to `ISO standard` and/or play around with font settings.

---

The dimension style of the second picture looks like the default for a new AutoCAD file - the style of the first picture has been altered, so you'll have to change the setting of the second file to match.

To alter the style of your dimensions, you need to use the aptly named Dimension Style settings. I'm using AutoCAD 2014, but I imagine it's a similar process for other versions.

You can try and find the toolbar button if you want, but it's also easily reachable by beginning to type `'dimstyle'` while you have nothing else selected and selecting the appropriate option, which should open a box that looks like this:

> [image: Start]
>
> As you can see from the picture, the circle dimension created by the radius tool is in the style of Picture 2 from the question.

Click `New...` and then `Continue` to create your new style.
A new window will open at this point where you can customise the various aspects of your dimensions. Having access to the original file allows you to compare the two styles and make the appropriate changes - other users looking at this question won't, so I'll make a note of what to do next.

There are two main differences between the two - the text being horizontal, and the font.

1. The font

   - Open the `Text` tab on the the New Dimension Style window. There will be a heading labeled `Text style`. Click the small box with 3 dots in.
   - On the right side of the screen, click the button `New...`. Name it something appropriate, then double click it in the Styles menu on the left to make sure you're editing the correct one.
   - Click the drop-down box under `Font Name`. Select any font to suit, `Arial Unicode MS` matches Picture 1 fairly well.
   - Click apply to return to the previous screen. Make sure your text style is the one selected in the drop-down box.
2. The text alignment

   - Go to the text tab once again.
   - In the box labeled `Text Alignment`, make sure the button for `ISO standard` is pressed.
3. Your screen should look something like this. Note the differences on the preview screen.

> [image: Done Box]

After hitting ok, you'll have to redraw your dimension in the new style - they don't automatically update.

> [image: Final]